# How do I get my Ravencoin wallet address on Ravencore?

Tags: wallet, altcoin

Very new to this, and couldn't find help on Google.

Answer (score -1):

Click on receive on the left vertical bar. Below the input boxes you will see "Request Payment." There you will be able to see your address.